# perl6 Is using junctions in matching possible?

Tags: match, raku, junction

Is it possible to use junction to match any of the values in a junction? I want to match any of the values in an array. What is the proper way to do it?

```
lisprog$ perl6
To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
> my @a=<a b c>
[a b c]
> any(@a)
any(a, b, c)
> my $x=any(@a)
any(a, b, c)
> my $y = "a 1"
a 1
> say $y ~~ m/ $x /
False
> say $y ~~ m/ "$x" /
False
> my $x = any(@a).Str
any("a", "b", "c")
> say $y ~~ m/ $x /
False
> say $y ~~ m/ || $x /
False
> say $y ~~ m/ || @a /
｢a｣
>
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Junctions are not meant to be interpolated into regexes. They're meant to be used in normal Perl 6 expressions, particularly with comparison operators (such as `eq`):

```perl
my @a = <x y z>;
say    "y" eq any(@a);  # any(False, True, False)
say so "y" eq any(@a);  # True
```

To match any of the values of an array in a regex, simply write the name of the array variable (starting with `@`) in the regex. By default, this is interpreted as an `|` alternation ("longest match"), but you can also specify it to be a `||` alternation ("first match"):

```perl
my @a = <foo bar barkeep>;
say "barkeeper" ~~ / @a /;     # ｢barkeep｣
say "barkeeper" ~~ / || @a /;  # ｢bar｣
```

Comment: Thank you again smls !! I Think Perl6 is really cool; I get things done faster with perl6 than with racket.