# How to use junction inside a perl6 regex interpolation?

Tags: regex, interpolation, raku, junction

Sometimes I have a long list and I would like to check whether a string matches anything in the list. I am trying to interpolate a junction inside a regex. They are all errors.

```
say "12345" ~~ m/ <{ (2,3,4).any }> /
Cannot resolve caller MAKE_REGEX(Int, Bool, Bool, Int, PseudoStash); none of these signatures match:

say "12345" ~~ m/ $( (2,3,4).any ) /
This type cannot unbox to a native string: P6opaque, Junction
```

Does this error message mean that junctions cannot be used inside regex interpolation?

The work-around I have is

```
say "12345" ~~ m/ <{ (2,3,4).join("||") }> /
｢2｣
```

How can I use junctions inside regex interpolation?

Comment: It seems the first case compiles if you put a [`so`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/so) in front of the junction: `say "12345" ~~ m/ <{ so (2,3,4).any }> /` (but I don't think this solves the problem though)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Sometimes I have a long list and I would like to check whether a string matches anything in the list.

Use a list, not a Junction:

```
my @list = <bar bartoo baragain>;
say 'bartoo' ~~ / @list /;                         # ｢bartoo｣
say 'bartoo' ~~ / <{<bar bartoo baragain>}> /;     # ｢bartoo｣
```

Note that by default you get the longest matching token.

> I am trying to interpolate a junction inside a regex. They are all errors. ... Does this error message mean that junctions cannot be used inside regex interpolation?

I think so. (The error message is perhaps LTA.) Junctions are a feature of the main P6 language. It seems reasonable that the pattern matching [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) doesn't support them.

> The work-around I have is

```
say "12345" ~~ m/ <{ (2,3,4).join("||") }> /
｢2｣
```

If you join with a doubled pipe (`||`) then you get the first token that matches rather than the longest:

```
say 'bartoo' ~~ / <{'bar || bartoo || baragain'}> /; # ｢bar｣
say 'bartoo' ~~ / ||@list /;                         # ｢bar｣
say 'bartoo' ~~ / ||<{<bar bartoo baragain>}> /;     # ｢bar｣
```

*Not* specifying the pipe symbol for these constructs is the same as specifying a single pipe symbol (`|`) and matches the longest matching token:

```
say 'bartoo' ~~ / <{'bar | bartoo | baragain'}> /; # ｢bartoo｣
say 'bartoo' ~~ / |@list /;                        # ｢bartoo｣
say 'bartoo' ~~ / |<{<bar bartoo baragain>}> /;    # ｢bartoo｣
```

---

You've asked related questions before. I'll add links to a couple of them here for convenience:

- [Is using junctions in matching possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41457242/perl6-is-using-junctions-in-matching-possible)
- [Interpolate array in match for AND, OR, NOT functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50829126/perl6-interpolate-array-in-match-for-and-or-not-functions/50838441#50838441)