# Difference between single pipe and double pipe in Raku Regex (| Vs ||)

Tags: raku, nqp

There are two types of alternation in Raku's regex: the `|` and `||`. What is the difference ?

```
say 'foobar' ~~ / foo || foobar /  # ｢foo｣
say 'foobar' ~~ / foo | foobar /   # ｢foobar｣
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- The [||](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#Alternation:_||) is the old alternation behaviour: try alternation from the first declared to the last
- The [|](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#Longest_alternation:_|) try alternation from the longest to the shortest declarative **atom**. It is called the [Longest Token Matching Spec](https://design.raku.org/S05.html#Longest-token_matching) strategy.

```
say 'foobar' ~~ / foo || foobar /  # ｢foo｣ is the first declared
say 'foobar' ~~ / foo | foobar /   # ｢foobar｣ is the longest token
```

More detailed answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53992397/2544873)